# MongoError: no mongos proxy available

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, kubernetes, gcloud

I am running a MongoDB service in Kubernetes and I am trying to connect with MongoDB service to another back-end services. I deployed MongoDB service to following codelabs tutorial. here is the tutorial link

> https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-mongodb-statefulset/index.html?index=..%2F..index#8)

MongoDB service is running properly and I can create a database through a shell command.

when I try to connect with nodejs back-end using `mongoose` I am getting below error

> MongoError: no mongos proxy available

here is my mongos connection URL

`mongodb://mongo-0.mongo,mongo-1.mongo,mongo-2.mongo:27017/food_content`

Answer (score 1):

First of all that tutorial was last updated on Feb/2017. I recommend you to read a more recent tutorial.

You should read about how [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) work.
In particular, [according to this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#pod-identity) you can access a service through

```
$(service name).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local
```

And a Pod with:

```
$(podname).$(service name).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local
```

Example:

```
mongo-0.mongo.default.svc.cluster.local
```